# How to resize AlertDialog on the Keyboard display

Tags: android, view, resize, android-alertdialog, android-softkeyboard

I have a `AlertDialog` box with approximately 10 controls (text and `TextView`) on it. These controls are in a `ScrollView` with `AlertDialog`, plus I got 2 buttons positive and negative. The issue I have is when the soft keyboard pops up the two buttons are hidden behind the keyboard.

I was looking for something like redraw function on my inner View or the dialog box. Below is the screen shot of what I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If your dialog was an activity using one of the Dialog themes you could effect this behavior by setting the `adjustResize` flag for the `windowSoftInputMode` parameter of the activity.

I'm using:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

I think you can still use this flag with regular dialogs, but I'm not sure how to apply it.  You may have to create your AlertDialog with a custom theme that inherits the right parent theme and also sets that flag, or you might have to use ContextThemeWrappers and stuff.

Or maybe you can just use [Window#setSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode(int)).

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: The last line works for me, ideally i suppose that was the question here and this is the correct answer. The selected answer is more of a design change suggestion than a correct answer. +1 for the answer

Comment: if you have a custom style, you can also make it an element of the style definition `<style name="Theme.MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"><item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateHidden</item></style>`

Comment: This answer should've been the accepted one. The last line of code did the trick for me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Works with FragmentDialog too!

Comment: A million times this. You need to set the SoftInputMode of the Dialog itself.

Comment: The last line of code did the trick, I tried doing it on the Activity's onCreate and seting it on the manifest, but I guess the do not share the same window.

Answer (score 18):

I've found a best way to handle this. Because this is a dialog, So the code

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

doesn't work very well.

Besides this code, you must set a dialog style for this dialog. The style should like below:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    ......
    ......
</style>
```

NOTICE that the attribute `parent` is `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` like an activity's style. and the attribute `android:windowFullScreen` should be `false`.

Now, the dialog will be resized when the soft keyboard toggles.

Comment: this worked for me but I used `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"` but setting false to `"android:windowFullscreen"` did do the trick...thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing worked for me except `adjustPan`

as per the documentation

> The activity's main window is not resized to make room for the soft keyboard. Rather, the contents of the window are automatically panned so that the current focus is never obscured by the keyboard and users can always see what they are typing. This is generally less desirable than resizing, because the user may need to close the soft keyboard to get at and interact with obscured parts of the window.

So just simply use it in your onCreate() or onCreateView() method like:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Or simply put `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in manifest for the Activiry in which we are playing with dialogs

and use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"` in each edittext which will help the user to navigate to next textbox easily.

**Point to remember**

Never use *MATCH_PARENT* to make the dialog full screen as `adjustPan` will not work here. If anyone wants to make the dialog to fit the screen, just use points till 0.96 (not more than this) for the height, so the keyboard will properly reach to the edittext. I did like below :

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        //int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        //int width = (int)(size.x * 0.96);
        int h = (int)(size.y * 0.96);

        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, h);
    }
}
```

Look, If I will use the total height (MATCH_PARENT) then soft_keyboard will squize the dialog. But if I will use points for the height (here 0.96 which is almost near to match_parent), then it will properly work.

Hope it will help someone :)

Answer (score 2):

maybe you don't need to resize Dialog

add android:imeOptions="actionNext" to EditText(all but last) (it will add "Next" button to the keyboard - go to next EditText)

and add android:imeOptions="actionDone" to last EditText ("Done" button - hide keyboard)

now user should be able to click buttons

if you're creating textboxes in code use EditText#setImeOptions function

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the info but that is not quite how the user will behave in this case. That is they have the freedom to only fill one or more of the textbox not all

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to have it as a popup? The popup looks so large, that you may just want to have it as a separate activity. In general, popups are used to provide a brief question or statement with a few options, not a full blown data entry form. Since you can't see much behind the large popup, you're not exposing any underlying controls anyways.

Comment: While your answer sounds true to me, it doesn't address edge cases.  What about a medium sized Dialog on a tablet?

Comment: True, I was thinking handheld, given the screenshot. If you're doing a seperate UI for a tablet, I suppose that a medium sized dialog for a tablet may work, but I think in general, a Dialog should be used for very small data entry, and notifications only. If you're trying to make something a form, have it as a seperate activity.

Comment: But this does not answer the question.

Comment: @ViliusK I know it doesn't answer his exact question, but I offered an alternative UI suggestion that makes things cleaner for the user and easier to implement. If he did not like the suggestion, then it's up to him as the poster to downvote or ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

to show keyboard immediately and adjust size:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To those who are in the same situation as me.

in my case, the problem was activity having these attributes in style

```xml
<style name="SomeStyleName">
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

If `windowTranslucentStatus` and `windowTranslucentNavigation` both are true,
the keyboard came up as it overlay dialog.

So I override those values to false, only for materialAlertDialog. (maybe AlertDialog or Dialog in your case)

```xml
<style name="SomeStyleName">
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
   <item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/TranslucentMaterialAlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="TranslucentMaterialAlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
</style>
```