# hiding half dialog at the top when soft keyboard is on

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

I have a dialog with an edit text inside. Once I open the keyboard I have two options :
 1. resize the layout - and then the edittext is simply gone(visually).
 2. pan - the edit text is shown partially and I do see every line I write in it. 
 BUT - the keyboard hides the Button at the bottom of the dialog (beneath the edittext)

I know it's possible in iOS. But is it possible in Android to simply lift the dialog to the top so that only half of it is seen ?

here's a picture to depict what I'm aiming at :
[image]

Comment: Just wrap your layout in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: of the dialog itself? or the one hosting it

Comment: I think this post might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5622202/how-to-resize-alertdialog-on-the-keyboard-display?answertab=active#tab-top

**getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);**

Answer (score 1):

In your Manifest file add the following code for this particular activity

```
<activity android:name="yourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
</activity>
```

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) doc for more info.

**EDIT**

try these.. may it works for you.

1. `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`
2. `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

Comment: that didn't either :/

Answer (score 0):

Use `adjustResize` with `adjustPan`

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

if it looks ugly then use `ScrollView` in dailog by using `customview.`

Comment: scrollview on dialog itself? not the fragment hosting it?

Answer (score 0):

For dialog, you need to do it in the dialog.

```
dialog!!.window!!.setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```