# Resize DialogFragment when keyboard is visible

Tags: java, android, xamarin

*(I am working with Xamarin C# but the code is identical to Java)*

I created a `DialogFragment` which inflates a custom layout. The `OnCreateView` looks like this :

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.dialog_feedback, container);
  int scale = Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
  int height = scale / 2;
  Dialog.Window.SetLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, height);
  Dialog.Window.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Bottom | GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal);
  return view;
}
```

And the `OnCreate` looks like this :

```
public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
  SetStyle(0, Resource.Style.dialog_no_border);
}
```

Here's the style :

```
<style name="dialog_no_border" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
  <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
  <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

The layout that the dialog is inflating contains a `ConstraintLayout` as the parent and has a `AppCompatEditText` inside it.

When i open the dialog and click on the EditText, the keyboard overlaps the Edittext. What i'm trying to do is, when the keyboard pops up, it should push up the `DialogFragment` and show the EditText above itself. How do i achieve that ?

I tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`, `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the `activity` tag inside the manifest, but with no luck!

So, how do i achieve this ?

Comment: [Try this solution, hope it will work for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7435225/11856637)

Comment: @Shivam Sorry, it didn't :(

Comment: Does the inflating layout has scrollview ?? or the parent activity has scroll view ?? try adding scrollview to both

Comment: They parent activity doesn't have a scrollView, it rather has a ViewPager which loads multiple fragments. I am opening the DialogFragment from inside one of the fragments. 
So where should i add the ScrollView ? @Rj_Innocent_Coder

Comment: you should add scroll view to parent activity but still please add xml of your layout and fragments file, I just solved exect issue today and it get solved by adding scrollview to activity.

Comment: @Rj_Innocent_Coder, as i mentioned, i can't directly add scrollview to the parent activity. It has a tablayout and a ViewPager to load multiple fragments. However, the parent fragment that opens up the DialogFragment has a ScrollView in it. But the DialogFragment itself doesn't have a ScrollView. So, any ideas on what to do here ?

Comment: please try to add layout files

Comment: @Rj_Innocent_Coder, already fixed it. It happened due to using the custom style for the dialog.

Comment: Cheers, Keep Coding..